# Error while validation firebase token send from android app

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

When I try to authenticate the token send from android app using google sign-in provider, I get following error:

```
{"message":"Unauthorized - Token is invalide: The value 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...' is not a verified ID token:\n- - The token is expired\n- - The token was not issued by the given issuers\n- - The token is not allowed to be used by this audience\n- - Token signature mismatch\n"}
```

But when I authorize from web using email/password provider it works

```
$idTokenString = $request->input('token');


    try { // Try to verify the Firebase credential token with Google

        $verifiedIdToken = $auth->verifyIdToken($idTokenString);
        dd($verifiedIdToken);

    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) { // If the token has the wrong format

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized - Can\'t parse the token: ' . $e->getMessage()
        ], 401);

    } catch (Exception $e) { // If the token is invalid (expired ...)

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized - Token is invalide: ' . $e->getMessage()
        ], 401);
```

Comment: have same problem. our backend server sending in android app this error. Any updates to your problem?..

Comment: @danyapd no, I just decoded the jwt and get payload. It was pet project

Comment: I've found my problem - I was sending Google JWT from app to backend. But it must be Firebase JWT.

Comment: so with Google's `getIdToken()` you getting `AuthCredential` from `GoogleAuthProvider`. Then you do `firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential()` with `addOnCompleteListener()` - `onComplete` should be `Task<AuthResult>` and then you can get `task.getResult().getToken()`